# How to reformat data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I apologize in advance if my question is not clear, I am just starting to learn Javascript and this my first post.I am trying to reformat a data set:

`console.log(dataset)` display the following (I am displaying here a few records):

```
[{"name":"HPH","income":["1976","2434"]},
{"name":"HPH","income":["1977","1658"]},
{"name":"HPH","income":["1978","1712"]},
{"name":"SWO","income":["1976","9913"]},
{"name":"SWO","income":["1977","8852"]},
{"name":"SWO","income":["1978","7152"]}]
```

I would like to get the following:

```
[{"name":"HPH","income":[["1976","2434"],["1977","1658"],["1978","1712"]]},
{"name":"SWO","income":[["1976","9913"],["1977","8852"],["1978","7152"]]}]
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Frank

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Have a look into the Array methods. Filter, map and reduce are excellent to do this type of transforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try also, just using `filter` and `reduce`:

```js
var dataset = [{"name":"HPH","income":["1976","2434"]},{"name":"HPH","income":["1977","1658"]},{"name":"HPH","income":["1978","1712"]},{"name":"SWO","income":["1976","9913"]},{"name":"SWO","income":["1977","8852"]},{"name":"SWO","income":["1978","7152"]}];

var result = dataset.reduce(function(data, item){
    var existitem = data.filter(function(i){
        return i.name === item.name
    })[0] || {name: item.name, income: []};

    !existitem.income.length && data.push(existitem);
    existitem.income.push(item.income);
    return data
}, [])

document.write(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the people that took the time to answer my question, much appreciated.  Frank

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var data = [{"name":"HPH","income":["1976","2434"]},
{"name":"HPH","income":["1977","1658"]},
{"name":"HPH","income":["1978","1712"]},
{"name":"SWO","income":["1976","9913"]},
{"name":"SWO","income":["1977","8852"]},
{"name":"SWO","income":["1978","7152"]}];

var final = [],
    found = false,
    i, j;
for (i in data) {
    for(j in final) {
        if (final[j].name == data[i].name) {
            found = true;
            final[j].income.push(data[i].income);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        found = false;
        continue;
    }

    var obj = {name: data[i].name, income: [data[i].income]};
    final.push(obj);
}

console.log(final);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wqq1t2zj/

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [{"name":"HPH","income":["1976","2434"]},
{"name":"HPH","income":["1977","1658"]},
{"name":"HPH","income":["1978","1712"]},
{"name":"SWO","income":["1976","9913"]},
{"name":"SWO","income":["1977","8852"]},
{"name":"SWO","income":["1978","7152"]}],
    b = {},
    c = [];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(!b[a[i].name])b[a[i].name] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < a[i].income.length){
        b[a[i].name].push(a[i].income[j]);
    }
}

// Here you have an object like 
// b = {HPH : ["1976","2434", "1978","1712"], SWO : ["1977","8852", "1977","8852","1978","7152"};
for(var k in b){
    c.push({name : k, income : b[k]}
}
```

I invite you to read : [Eloquent JS](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) who's a very helpful reading and if you get the motivation ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/About_JavaScript) ([Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array))) to be a pro!